# Errors doing socket.io chat example node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chat

Just started to learn node.js for multiplayer capabilities:

Using windows 7, npm to install node.js and components
I had few issues which were making me mad

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

was throwing error:

```
D:\projects\node\chat\index.js:3
var io = require('socket.io').(http);
                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

some time more wiered unable to handle or no such method defined, etc.

On client side in the browser following script was not working

```
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
```

was throwing (not error) but message for each action you perform in web:

```
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
```

After doing lot of effort I come to two easy fixes shared in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first error you will have to use listen method of socket.io, otherwise it don't work ( while I was following this according to socket.io chat example )

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
```

the second prompt or problem, which suppose to be working but somehow you must have to define url in io.connect method

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be off base here, as I'm still learning node myself, but it appears to me the answer is more simple than the currently accepted (on 2014.7.21) suggests; you shouldn't have a `.` between `require('socket.io')` and `(http);` That would suggest it was some kind of anonymous function within the object returned by the `require` when it is actually the constructor that needs to be called.

It should look like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

I am not sure on the resolution to your second problem, as I did not encounter it. But I did find that I needed to encapsulate the jquery functions inside a `.ready()` which is standard practice. The result looks like this:

```
var socket = io();
$(function () {
    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
    $('#chatForm').submit(function () {
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });
});
```